# Why is my ifndef section not working?

Tags: wix, conditional-compilation

I have the following snippet in my `program.wxs` file:

```
<?ifndef $(var.TwoOnly) ?>
        <Feature Id="FeatureOne" ... >
          ...
        </Feature>
<?endif ?>

<?ifndef $(var.OneOnly) ?>
        <Feature Id="FeatureTwo" ... >
          ...
        </Feature>
<?endif ?>
```

I'm compiling this using the following comand:

```
candle -dOneOnly=1 program.wxs
```

Looking at the compiled `program.wixobj`, I can see that Feature Two's declaration is all there, and after running `light`, both features are listed, and the installer functions exactly as if neither `OneOnly` or `TwoOnly` were set. Why is my `ifndef` block not working correctly?

Note: I also have the following:

```
<?ifdef $(var.OneOnly) ?>
  <?define productName = One Only ?>
<?else?>
  <?ifdef $(var.TwoOnly) ?>
    <?define productName = Two Only ?>
  <?else?>
    <?define productName = Both ?>
  <?endif?>
<?endif?>
```

The name, even when `OneOnly` is set during compile, is displayed as `Both`.

**Edit**

I've reduced the complexity of my condition to the minimal case shown in [the documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm):

```
<?ifndef $(var.TwoOnly) ?>
  <?include featureOne.wxi ?>
<?endif?>
```

This still does not work.

Comment: Does it work if you define a variable in code instead of passing values via command line? Have you tried the examples from WiX.chm literally?

Comment: It doesn't work if I define in code. I haven't tried the `.chm` examples literally, but I'll have a go...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `ifdef` or `ifndef`, the variable must be stated *without* `$(var.)` syntax.

```
<?ifndef TwoOnly ?>
  <?include featureOne.wxi ?>
<?endif?>
```

This works.